# symfony2 + bootstrap 3 readonly select dropdown still editable

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am using symfony2 and bootstrap 3 and when I set the readonly attribute to a form field, it gets greyed and I have the forbidden cursor but the field is still editable (in my case a select dropdown).

The readonly attribute would work great for a simple text field, but not for a select.

How can I make sure users can't click a select and change its value ?

I can't use "disabled" as I need the value to be passed to the form.
Using jquery to rewrite the readonly attribute also did not work.

my form:

```
            ->add('product', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Produit',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:MarketPlace\Product',
                    'read_only' => true,
                ))
```

Comment: How can they still change it? Do they need to see the value?

Comment: well, when clicking the select control, the dropdown appears and they simply can select another option (even if it's greyed out). They need to see the value and I need to retrieve the value when posting the form. Plus this is part of a collection and added elements are not readonly. It seems other face the same issue, here in french (http://www.developpez.net/forums/d38029/webmasters-developpement-web/balisage-x-html-validation-w3c/html-readonly-select/)

Comment: Is there a condition for the select to be disabled? If so, maybe test this condition in your formbuilder and add a readonly text field if true, a select if not?

Comment: well, my product here is an entity (oneToMany with its parent). So I can't get a simple text field cause I'll get the error "scalar expected, etc), won't I?

Comment: You can get a text field from an entity by making a dataTransformer (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) and using it in your formbuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data transformer `ProductToTextTransformer` for your entity [as explained in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), and then use it in your formbuilder, adding a select or a readonly text according to the condition for the select to be disabled or not :

```
     //...

     // this assumes that the entity manager was passed in as an option
     $entityManager = $options['em'];
     $transformer = new ProductToTextTransformer($entityManager);
     if ($condition_to_disabled_the_select){
       $builder->add('product', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Produit',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:MarketPlace\Product',
            ));
     }
     else{
        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('product', 'text', array('label' => 'Produit', 'read_only' => true))
                    ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        );
     }
```

Comment: well, I can't use a hidden field for a onetomany entity attribute and if I put the hidden in the class, the second product field overrides the first one. it seems it's not working here.

Comment: I've edited my answer with elements from my other comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756626/symfony2-bootstrap-3-readonly-select-dropdown-still-editable/27756954#comment43926952_27756626), does it work for you?

Comment: well, yes, it should be working though I prefer to keep my javascript solution which I find lighter.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working but I don't liek it that much, I feel it's not clean like it should be:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(':input[readonly]').each(function(){
            $(this)
                .hide()
                .parent().append('<p>' + $(this).find(":selected").text() + '</p>')
        })
        ;
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today. I disabled every other select's option besides the selected one.

```
[
    'choice_attr' => static fn(?string $choice): array => ['disabled' => !$choice || $selectedValue !== $choice];
]
```

Hope it might help someone.